# Passing data in UIPageViewControllers Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController to navigate through several(5 in my case) view controllers. To keep this as simple as possible, I have 3 buttons on the first view controller and each button when pressed displays a different image on that same view controller.

I would like the image selected on the first view controller to show up (be passed to) another view controller, say the fifth viewcontroller. How do I go about this?
I don't have any buttons to go to the next view controllers (I'm using page curl navigation) and my views are not embedded in a navigation controller.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save selected images in the UIPageViewController object so every page(child) view controller can ask them via self.parentViewController.
For example, for the one selected image you need to create variable "selectedImage" in UIPageViewController object. Then in your first view controller in some button action you save your image in that var by calling:

```
let pageVC = self.parentViewController as! MyPageViewController
pageVC.selectedImage = selectedImage
```

Next, when your 5-th view controller will ready to be viewed and call his "viewDidLoad" you take your saved image in the same way you saved it and use it.

Comment: Kirander thanks for your reply. I'm a beginner and didn't quite understand. Do you mind expanding a little on how I can save selected images in the UIPageViewController object. And how will the child views get this data. Thanks very much.

Comment: his code is showing how to save the image to the parent page view controller (which you'll have to subclass to add a custom property). the child view can access its parent view with `self.parentViewController` if you have a property on the parent page view controller called, `selectedImage` (like `var selectedImage:UIImage?`) you can case the parent to your class to access that property like you would any object

Comment: Thanks very much kirander and gadu. I figured how how to save the image to the UIPageViewController but really couldn't figure out how to then pass the image to another child view. I ended up  saving my image choices to a struct containing global variables which could be easily accessed anywhere in my project using the following:                                                                       
   struct ImageVariables {
    static var image1: UIImage?
}. And to access the images in other Viewcontrollers I used ImageVariables.image1